# Graphic Cards causes crashes with recommended PSU

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, crash, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce

I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 TI that recommends a 650W PSU. (https://www.nvidia.com/en-me/geforce/graphics-cards/rtx-2080-ti/), my workstation is th HPZ600 (https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01709709#AbT3) with a 650W PSU as recommended.

On heavy GPU work i hear a click and the workstation crashes, the workstation doesen't make any sound or signal, setting the power consumption to its minimum using NVIDIA SMI reduces a little the problem.

My colleague has the same workstation and the AMD radeon rx vega that has the same recommended PSU and the same problem.

Why does this happen and how can I stop this crashes?

Best regards.

Comment: OEM manufacturers tend to be "optimistic" about the power draw of their PSUs and also have a slightly different focus about the power available on each rail. An OEM PSU might have two 120W 12 rails while a higher quality "gaming" PSU may have a single 300W 12V rail. The first thing you should do is get a good high quality PSU, preferably with a wattage beyond the "minimum" specification.

Comment: Graphics cards can also draw significantly higher than their rated power when they switch from low to high power modes before they settle into their "rated" power draw. A cheaper PSU might not be able to cope with that initial pulse and can cause system failures that way. An over-specified PSU will have more headroom to take up this initial load. It might be worth reading about "power excursions" https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/news/intel-atx-v3-psu-standard/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PSU recommended is for the GPUs also recommended on the same page, each of which has a <60W power draw.

The 2080Ti has a 300W draw [though I'd allow for 400 to be safe]. You need a much bigger PSU.

Comment: I'd wonder what the peak momentary draw (what Intel refers to in their ATX Specification as ["power excursions"](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/news/intel-atx-v3-psu-standard/2)) is for a 2080Ti as it ramps up is. Cards can very briefly draw far higher than their rated power draw and a cheap OEM PSU with under-specified components might collapse under a sudden heavy load.

Comment: What wattage do you recommend?

Comment: 650-60+400≈1000W

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I can't change the psu of the workstation, is it possible (and safe?) to add an external psu only for the graphic card?

Comment: That's well outside my field of expertise, sorry.

Comment: *Ok, the problem is that I can't change the psu of the workstation, is it possible (and safe?) to add an external psu only for the graphic card?* The short answer here is an emphatic no.